# HTML List step scrolling to top and bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a vertical list in my HTML. There is a top arrow and bottom arrow near that list. When I click top arrow, I want this list to go up step by step and opposite for the bottom arrow. the following is my html and Angular code.

```
<div class="verticalCarousel">
<a ng-click="scrolltoBottom();" class="scroll-to-bottom">BOTTOM</a>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs  verticalCarouselGroup" role="tablist" id="messagestab" >
        <li role="presentation">
            TEST
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            TEST
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            TEST
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            TEST
        </li>

        <li role="presentation">
            TEST
        </li>

        <li role="presentation">
            TEST
        </li>
  </ul>

  <a ng-click="scrolltoTop();" class="scroll-to-top">TOP</a>
</div>
```

Here is the Angular code.

```
var i = 1;
    $scope.scrolltoBottom = function(){
        var list = $(".verticalCarouselGroup");
        var container = $(".verticalCarousel");
        console.log(list.height()-list.offset().top+"= BOTTOM OF CARO")
        console.log(container.height()-container.offset().top+"= BOTTOM OF container")

        i = i+50;
        list.css({
            'position': 'relative',
            'top':i ,
        }); 
    };

    $scope.scrolltoTop = function(){
        var list = $(".verticalCarouselGroup");
        var container = $(".verticalCarousel");
        console.log(list.height()-list.offset().top+"= BOTTOM OF CARO")
        console.log(container.height()-container.offset().top+"= BOTTOM OF container")

        i = i-50;
        list.css({
            'position': 'relative',
            'top':i ,
        });         

    };
```

I added a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/arunkumarthekkoot/863z3kky/2/

Comment: what do you mean by :  list to go up step by step? Can you prepare a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Himanshu Tyagi Please see this https://jsfiddle.net/arunkumarthekkoot/863z3kky/2/

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: simply if the list have more items I want to see the items by clicking the up/down arrows

Comment: Follow You need to put something like this in your code


http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8fygutd/1/)

```
angular.module("testApp", []).controller('ScrollCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.scrolltoBottom = function() {
    var list = $(".verticalCarouselGroup");
    list.animate({ "marginTop": "+=50px" }, "slow");
  };

  $scope.scrolltoTop = function() {
  var list = $(".verticalCarouselGroup");
    list.animate({ "marginTop": "-=50px" }, "slow");
  };
}]);
```

To stop it from scrolling you can add checks for bottom and top.

**Hint** : compare bottom top with marginTop : (`list.css('marginTop')`)

Comment: Yeah this is a nice idea , but compare with bottom top means ?

Comment: I mean stop scrolling up when u have reached on top and scrolling down when u have reached bottom. So grab top and bottom values and compare them with current state when up or down is pressed.

Comment: Check out the working jsfiddle.. You need to add the stop code only.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you're looking for scroll down steps by steps on li elements just on clicking on the arrow ?

If that's it :
You could maybe use smooth scroll plugin like ui.kit and trigger a click event in `setTimeout` or `setIntervall` which scroll down on every element following an array like

```
myListEl = ['#first', '#second', etc...];
```

http://getuikit.com/docs/smooth-scroll.html